# Migrating datasets and pipelines from one DF to the other DF

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a a data factory where there are 7 pipelines and respective data sets were built. Now those data sets and pipelines needs to be moved from that data factory to other data factory. May I know which is the best way to migrate all the pipelines and data sets from one DF to the other? Step by step process would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this previous Stack Overflow thread pertaining to the same question: [How to export pipeline in datafactory v2 or migrate to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320386/how-to-export-pipeline-in-datafactory-v2-or-migrate-to-another/)

Another option is to use Visual Studio, where you can export the configuration from one and import to another ADF instance. Some reconfiguration steps are necessary.